# My CSS rule works partly. Can you help me?

Tags: html, css, font-family

This is the main code,

```
<div id="text-12" class="widget widget_text">
    <div class="heading">
        <h3>
            title
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="textwidget">
        text
    </div>
</div>
```

And I added this CSS rule,

```
#text-12 {
    font-family: "courier new" !important;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Unfortunately, the **font-family** only work for the class **textwidget** and I can not apply **font-family** to **heading** class with any trick. What is wrong?

One thing more, Page address: http://sciself.com/?page_id=4766 (Right Sidebar)

Comment: Looks fine to me in Chrome.

Comment: @j08691 No No, the word "تماس" have different font. please have a closer look.

Comment: The question itself does not sufficiently describe the problem: the real problem is in CSS code not disclosed. A link to a live page is *not* enough for a problem description.

Comment: The font is set in a style sheet in a manner that overrides the setting in the question. Using a browser’s developer tools, it should be simple to track it down, so that you can write a rule with a more specific selector (and the `!important` specifier, if the overriding rule has it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your overwriting the font-family of H3 later in your css file?

Edit: I'm quite sure since everything seems the work fine.

```
<div id="text-12" class="widget widget_text">
<div class="heading">
     <h3>
        Heading
    </h3>

</div>
<div class="textwidget">Textwidget</div>
```

Note, I've changed the text to made it easier to read (for me)

[Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkV9D/)

I inspected your page. You may use some rule more specific to override the parent CSS file. For example,

```
#sidebar #text-12 .heading h3 {
    font-family: "courier new" !important;
}
```

Comment: You were right. I added some code to your answer. have a look and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this into your css

```
#text-12 {
font-family: "courier new" !important;
direction: rtl;
}

#text-12 h3 {
font-family: "courier new" !important;
direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: Done, but, Not effective

Answer (score 0):

try to put

```
.heading h3{
    font-family: "courier new" !important;
}
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it looks different to you because the h3 are bold by default. Try changing the font-weight setting to see if that is what you are looking for.

```
 #text-12 h3 {
 font-family: "courier new";
 font-weight: normal;
 direction: rtl;
}
```

You shouldn't have to use the !important - as that is normally bad practice.

Comment: Do you have !important on any other font styles? They might be overriding your header font.